# How to apply Local Storage to a to-do list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm working on an app, and one section of this app is like a to-do list. The user can add and delete list-items.
I've been trying to apply local storage to this list, but I can't do it.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="entrada" placeholder="" />
<a href="#" data-role="button" id="agregar">Add</a>
<ul id="list" data-role="listview">
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('#agregar').on('click', function()
{
$('#agregar').on('click', function(event) { $('#entrada').val("")})

var entrada = $('#entrada').val();
if($("#entrada").val() == '')
{ return false; }
$('#list').append( '<li><a hreft="#">'+entrada+<'</a></li>' );
$('#list').listview( 'refresh' );
}
)
```

Comment: Take a look at http://todomvc.com/ Has todo  app (with localStorage) code for numerous libraries and frameworks including jQuery. Source code will help you out

Comment: We could help you but there is no localStorage code or data structure shown in question. Without an attempt shown, or more specific problem mentioned,  it just looks like you need someone to write this for you. that's not really how this site works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working example of the list save in local storage so even if you closed the page and opened it again the to-do list still exists 
http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/mEwqzE

this is the code you have to change :

```
$('#agregar').on('click', function() {
  $('#agregar').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#entrada').val("")
  })

  var entrada = $('#entrada').val();
  if ($("#entrada").val() == '') {
    return false;
  }

  $('#list').append('<li><a hreft="#">' + entrada + '</a></li>');
  localStorage.setItem("todolist", $('#list').html());
  $('#entrada').val("");
  $('#list').listview('refresh');
})

$(function(){
  $('#list').html(localStorage.getItem("todolist"));
})();
```

Comment: Mina can I ask a follow up question. How would  you remove items from local storage in your codepen example.